# Is there a way to control flow of commands in Makefile using target extensions?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to execute different commands depending on the target extension, but I'm having trouble making `make` use the variable extracted from the target in the conditional.

When I do the same logic with the actual character (not the suffix inferred one) it works fine.

P.S.: I intend to use the extension without the dot in one of the target commands.

I was expecting that `make foo.a` would echo "yep" and `make foo.d` echo "nop", but all I get is "nop"

```
.PHONY: foo.%
foo.%:
    @echo $*
    @echo $(subst .,,$(suffix $@))
ifneq ($(filter $(subst .,,$(suffix $@)), a b c),)
    @echo 'yep'
else
    @echo 'nop'
endif
```

Also tried to use `$*` but that got me the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the fact that `ifeq` etc. are *preprocessor* statements in makefiles, which mean they're evaluated when the makefile is read in, while automatic variables like `$*` etc. are only set in the context of recipes and are assigned when make decides it wants to run the recipe, which is much much later than when the makefile is parsed.  So when these `ifeq` operations are evaluated the automatic variables like `$*` expand to the empty string.

If you want to behave differently depending on the target name you'll have to use in-recipe constructs such as shell comparisons, not makefile preprocessor statements like `ifeq`:

```
.PHONY: foo.%
foo.%:
        @echo $*
        @echo $(subst .,,$(suffix $@))
        @if [ '$*' = a -o '$*' = b -o '$*' = c ]; then \
            echo 'yep'; \
        else \
            echo 'nop'; \
        fi
```

Comment: Despite knowing how they worked, somehow I never before linked the term "preprocessor" to (GNU) `make` conditionals.  But it fits well.

Comment: If someone knows C or C++, thinking of them as preprocessor statements while recipes are "runtime" statements (and automatic variables are "local variables") is helpful.  But you can get confused if you go too far in that direction: for example it's not a good idea to start thinking of rules as "functions" that can be "called" as then you start trying to write your makefile as a procedural language when it's not.